# Dynamic SQL update Image

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, varbinary

I have been battling with this statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[transact_image_update]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@transact_recordID_int int, 
@image1_bin image, 
@image2_bin image, 
@transact_referenceNo_str nvarchar(25),
@userID_last uniqueidentifier,
@tableName nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

DECLARE @sqlUpdt01 nvarchar(4000)
SET @sqlUpdt01  = '
        Update [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] SET [image1_bin] = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @image1_bin), 2)      
        + ', [image2_bin] = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @image2_bin), 2)
        +', [userID_last] = '''+ convert(nvarchar(4000),@userID_last)
        + ''' WHERE (transact_recordID_int = '+convert(varchar,@transact_recordID_int) +')
            AND ([transact_referenceNo_str] = ''' +convert(varchar, @transact_referenceNo_str)
             +''' )
             AND (locked_bol = 0) 
             '  
exec sp_executesql @sqlUpdt01
```

Basically, I have many DB tables with similar schema but different names (for types of transactions) and would like this ONE procedure to make the update given the table name as argument. This script compiles successfully but execution cannot update the image field. Is there a conversion I'm missing?

Please help.

Comment: How do you know it "cannot update the image field"? Is there an error message? What do you see if you print out the value of `@sqlUpdt01` before execution?

Answer (score -1):

in correct type cast in below line

in correct line
+ '''  WHERE (transact_recordID_int = '+ convert(varchar,@transact_recordID_int) +

correct line
+ '''  WHERE (transact_recordID_int = '+ @transact_recordID_int +